# Issues with XamlWriter

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I've some issues with XamlWriter.
I've a button with a TextOptions:

```
<Button FontFamily="Calibri" FontSize="67" FontWeight="SemiBold" Tag="K -" Margin="1,1,1,1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" TextOptions.TextHintingMode="Animated" Grid.Column="4" Grid.Row="1">
```

try getting xaml with:

`string xaml = XamlWriter.Save(ctl);`

XamlWriter adds this line:

`xmlns:msim="clr-namespace:MS.Internal.Media;assembly=PresentationCore"`

and change TextOptions to TextOptionsInternal

`msim:TextOptionsInternal.TextHintingMode="Animated"`

When I try to load xaml with:

```
ParserContext parser = new ParserContext();
parser.XmlnsDictionary.Add("x", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml");
parser.XmlnsDictionary.Add("", "http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation");               
parser.XmlnsDictionary.Add("s", "clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib");
parser.XmlnsDictionary.Add("msim", "clr-namespace:MS.Internal.Media;assembly=PresentationCore");

UIElement el = System.Windows.Markup.XamlReader.Parse(xaml, parser) as UIElement;
```

I get the following error:

'Impossibile impostare il membro sconosciuto '{clr-namespace:MS.Internal.Media;assembly=PresentationCore}TextOptionsInternal.TextHintingMode'

I've tried everything but I can't solve it, any tips?

Thanks in advance, Stefano.

The only way to make it work that I've found is to use String.Replace to replace TextOptionsInternal with TextOptions and manually remove MS.Internal.Media reference

Comment: There is no way I'm afraid. You would have to setup a XAML type mapping which is not possible because of the internal framework type `TextOptionsInternal`. The problem with XAML serialization is that it is executed at runtime. And at runtime the XAML looks quite different. For example, some types will be replaced. That's what has happened to `TextOptions`. There are not so rare cases where you have to post-process the serialized output in order to be able to deserialize it again.

Comment: In you case you could accept to lose information and e.g. use regex to completely remove any `msim:` type references or replace the runtime types with the original design time types.

Comment: Thanks, I currently use regex to remove xmlns after serialization, I will extend this to other elements. The only way is to create a post parser to enable proper deserialization